# Excel Plugins for Apple and Windows

Tags: excel, rest

I want to make some REST calls from Excel and do some complicated operations.  I want to support both Apple and Windows machines.  I have investigated several options, and they mainly only work on Windows.  What is a good approach to make a multi-platform REST-driven plugin for Excel?  Is it even possible in Apple?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the version of Excel for Mac that you are talking about. As of Excel:Mac 2011, VBA has cross-platform support.  The only thing you'll have to check is that your references are available on both the Mac and PC.

Comment: Okay.  Is there a list of references available for Mac somewhere?